# Asyncpg/PostgreSQL (python/discord.py)

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py, asyncpg

I'm having an issue where my discord bot stops replying to commands that use the database (postgresql and asyncpg) after a load of traffic.

I've checked the db and it doesn't go offline or anything and I don't get any errors what so ever.

`help` works fine as it doesn't use the db

How I create/use the connection :

```py
#How I create the connection

async def create_connection_pool():
    bot.pg_conn = await asyncpg.create_pool(**credentials)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await create_connection_pool()

#How I use it

@voice.command()
    async def name(self, ctx,*, name):
        con = await self.bot.pg_conn.acquire()
        id = ctx.author.id
        voice = await self.bot.pg_conn.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM voice_channels WHERE user_id = $1", id)
        if voice is None:
            await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} You don't own a channel.")
        else:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(voice['voice_channel_id'])
            await channel.edit(name = name)
            await ctx.channel.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} You have changed the channel name to '+ '{}!'.format(name))
            voice = await self.bot.pg_conn.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE user_id = $1", id)
            if voice is None:
                async with con.transaction():
                    await con.execute("INSERT INTO user_settings VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", (id,name,0))
            else:
                async with con.transaction():
                    await con.execute("UPDATE user_settings SET channel_name = $1 WHERE user_id = $2", name, id)
        await self.bot.pg_conn.release(con)
```

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong ?

I've tried using try/except didn't get anything

Added a bunch of debug prints in there, doesn't get past

`15 | voice = await self.bot.pg\_conn.fetchrow("SELECT \* FROM voice\_channels WHERE user\_id = $1", id)`

and tried adding a timeout to the fetch and that didn't do anything.
although when I do keyboardinterupt it comes out of of the fetch just before shutting down and runs the print.

If someone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: voice.command isn't an actual function within discord.py..

Comment: That's a group command, which wasn't the issue.
After doing more research and lots of testing I figured out what the issue was I had too many connection open and asyncpg only allows 10 connections to be used at once (on default if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Ah alright, fair enough to ya